# npm formidable form returns last checkbox value only

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I am using npm formidable (https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) to handle forms in my express js application.

I have this form:

```
<form action="/getchecks" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="set-featured-form">
    <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="1">News 1 heading <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="2">News 2 heading <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="4">News 4 heading <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="5">News 5 <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="6">news 6 <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" value="7">news 7 <br>
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="save-featured">
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want the user to be able to select multiple checkboxes and then on submission I want to get what checkboxes were checked. But, in this case, it only returns the last checked checkbox. For eg: If I check 1, 5 & 7, it will return only 7. This is my router code:

```
router.post('/getchecks', function (req, res, next){
    getCheckboxes(req, res);  
});

function getCheckboxes(req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.write('received the data:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({
            fields: fields
        }));
    });

}
```

And this is the output:

```
received the data:

{ fields: { featured: '7' } }
```

How can I make it pass me the array of values for the checked checkboxes?

Thanks.

Comment: Try making the name unique, as that's used to refer to the data in the JSON. You want the name to be unique except when it is a radio button, because the name groups the radio button selector.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding [] to the end of featured?

```
<form action="/getchecks" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="set-featured-form">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[]" value="1">News 1 heading <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[]" value="2">News 2 heading <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[]" value="4">News 4 heading <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[]" value="5">News 5 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[]" value="6">news 6 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[]" value="7">news 7 <br>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="save-featured">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like this has been fixed: [#380](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/pull/380/files)

However, this PR hasn't been merged with the master branch!

I made the local changes and it does work.

Comment: That's correct. It's not in the master yet. I tried copying code in the node_module and it worked fine.